# How to run modular multi-package JUnit test suits?

Tags: java, junit, test-suite, module-info, java-16

I'm trying to run all tests (packaged across many different subpackages) in a given (Java-16, modular) project, using the test suite feature of JUnit (4); but this is much harder than I'd like it to be, seemingly requiring an `-add-opens` JVM option per test (sub)package. Does a better solution exist?

A MVE would be a project `mve` with test suite

```
package mve.test;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;

import mve.test.sub.HelloTest;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses(HelloTest.class)
public class AllTests {
    // Empty by design.
}
```

and the (only) test in the subpackage `mve.test.sub` being

```
package mve.test.sub;

import org.junit.Test;

import mve.main.Hello;

public class HelloTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        Hello.main(null);
    }
}
```

The project exports nothing and requires nothing, which is how I'd like to keep it.

Is there any way to do this without adding `--add-opens mve/mve.test.xxx=ALL-UNNAMED` for each and every single subpackage `xxx` to the JVM?

If not, this is a heavy blow against using (a lot of) packages for your test classes.

Comment: You want the tests to be invoked by an external framework. Why do you refuse to export the test cases’ packages then?

Comment: Afaik, the maven patches the module under test with the test code, and opens all packages - at least last time I checked.

Comment: @Holger I don't event want to have my tests in my exported code. To my understanding, this is part of the whole concept of separating main and test code. This is supported in Eclipse (for instance) by the "Contains test sources" option. See also [Testing in a modular world](https://info.michael-simons.eu/2021/10/19/testing-in-a-modular-world/)

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Yes, Maven does that for you. However, that only helps if you run your tests from Maven, which doesn't give you the most user-friendly way to handle debugging in (say) Eclipse. I would prefer to be able to invoke the tests directly from Eclipse, hence my question

Comment: Apparently, the problem is that you have your test cases inside the same module as the production code. Just don’t do that. Put your test cases in a module of its own, then it can be open, without affecting the production code module.

Comment: By the way, did you read the article to the end, including the comment that says that you don’t need to specify `--add-opens` when you make the tests `public`?

Answer (score 0):

With Junit 5 it works like this:

Create a suite class to run the tests of all modules like this:

```
package com.project;

import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectModules;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.Suite;

@Suite
@SelectModules({
  "com.module1",
  "com.module2",
  "com.module3",
})
class AllTests {}
```

In each tested module the exported packages have to be opened to Junit, e.g.:

```
module com.module1
{
  exports com.module1.packageA;
  exports com.module1.packageB;
  
  opens com.module1.packageA to org.junit.platform.commons;
  opens com.module1.packageB to org.junit.platform.commons;
  
  requires org.junit.jupiter.api;
  requires ...
}
```

And of course each module must have its own tests inside.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion; it looks like it should do the trick (at the cost of adding an opens-clause to module.info for every project subpackage, which, while not ideal, I agree is better than adding an --add-opens option for each test package to the JVM).  One question though: you also added exports clauses, but surely those are optional? Your setup would still work if the main project exports nothing, right? In fact, it seems to me that the exports clauses subsume the opens clauses.

Comment: I suppose that the exports are not necessary for the test, but each module usually exports some packages and in my experience those are usually the packages which need to be opened to JUnit.